# Merge objects in array without overriding different value properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to merge objects in an array with the same `id` without overriding different value properties.

```js
var arr = [{
  Messages: { count: 1 },
  Account: { key: 'TEST' },
  id: 179,
  Contact:
  {
    firstName: 'The Postman',
    lastName: 'Team'
  },
  Tags: { name: 'forums', color: '#0091EA' }
},
{
  Messages: { count: 1 },
  Account: { key: 'TEST' },
  id: 179,
  Contact:
  {
    firstName: 'The Postman',
    lastName: 'Team'
  },
  Tags: { name: 'defective', color: '#0091EA' }
}];

var tags = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  tags = tags.concat(arr[i].Tags);
}

var result = arr[0];
result.Tags = tags;
 
console.log(result);
```

My goal is is to have the following object:

```
var obj =
{ Messages: { count: 1 }, 
  Account: { key: "TEST" }, 
  id: 179, 
  Contact: { firstName: "The Postman", lastName: "Team" }, 
  Tags: [{ name: "forums", color: "#0091EA" }, { name: "defective", color: "#0091EA" }] 
};
```

I've created a fiddle where I managed to get the desired output, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/18mLhx7j/1/

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer posted by **@Harun Yilmaz** I was able to accomplish the same result using Lodash reduce.
I just wonder if it's a valid alternative to what he posted.

```js
var arr = [
{ Messages: { count: 1 }, 
  Account: { key: "TEST" }, 
  id: 179, 
  Contact: { firstName: "The Postman", lastName: "Team" }, 
  Tags: { name: "forums", color: "#0091EA" } },
{ Messages: { count: 1 }, 
  Account: { key: "TEST" }, 
  id: 179, 
  Contact: { firstName: "The Postman", lastName: "Team" }, 
  Tags: { name: "defective", color: "#0091EA" } }
];

var interactions =_.reduce(arr, function(acc, cur) { 
    for (let i =0; i < Object.keys(cur).length; i++) {
        let key = Object.keys(cur)[i];
        if (!acc[key]) {
            acc[key] = cur[key];
        } else if (acc[key] && !_.isArray(acc[key]) && !_.isEqual(acc[key], cur[key])) {
            var obj = [];
            obj.push(acc[key]);
            obj.push(cur[key]);
            acc[key] = obj;
        } else if (acc[key] && _.isArray(acc[key])) {
            acc[key].push(cur[key]);
        }
    }
return acc;
}, {});

console.log(interactions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it always the case that only Tags will be different and other properties will always be same?

Comment: I see two ways. First, you take a set, which can take duplicate object. Second, you change the equals() method of your object in order to take more than the id into account

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @amrendersingh it is at the moment, but it may change in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to have a final object and [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as following

```js
var arr = [
{ Messages: { count: 1 }, 
  Account: { key: "TEST" }, 
  id: 179, 
  Contact: { firstName: "The Postman", lastName: "Team" }, 
  Tags: { name: "forums", color: "#0091EA" } },
{ Messages: { count: 1 }, 
  Account: { key: "TEST" }, 
  id: 179, 
  Contact: { firstName: "The Postman", lastName: "Team" }, 
  Tags: { name: "defective", color: "#0091EA" } }
];

const finalArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const {Tags,...Rest} = cur;
 
 acc.Tags.push(Tags);
 
 acc = {
  ...Rest,
  Tags: acc.Tags
 };
 
 
 return acc;

},{Tags:[]});
// ^^ initial object

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Thank you, can you provide also a non ES6 alternative?

Comment: What if my array has multiple ids?

Comment: @amrendersingh The last id will overwrite the value.